# Facebook chat plugin blocking nav header

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website where I'm using fb chat plugin. It was working fine until last couple of weeks. Recently I've observed that when the plugin loads, there's a hidden iframe which covers the entire right side of the page. This iframe's max height is calc(100% - 80px) so it covers the entire page height and it's z-index is 2147483646, so the nav buttons below are not clickable. However, if the chat window is opened and closed once then this issue disappears.

Now I have tried many options like setting up a custom css to reset the max-height to 0px when the plugin loads and then remove the css when the plugin is clicked to open the chat window. None of these are working. I cannot move the chat plugin to left of the page also.

Have anyone faced similar issue or can suggest any workaround?

[image: iframe issue]